# Parent variable is not updated for the ChildViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, swift4

I have a class which is inherited from `BaseViewController.swift`. I have defined a flag for core data changes tracking:

```
var coreDataUpdated: Bool?
```

I've also added an observer for core data changes in `viewWillAppear` of `BaseViewController.swift`

```
//Core data update
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.CoreDataUpadated),
                                 name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
                                 object: nil)
```

Now whenever I notified about changes in core data, I change `coreDataUpdated` variable to `true`

```
@objc func CoreDataUpadated() {
    self.coreDataUpdated = true
}
```

Now in my `ChildViewController.swift` in `viewDidAppear` when I check for `coreDataUpdated` it returns me `nil`

here is my complete code:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var coreDataUpdated: Bool?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Core data update
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                      selector: #selector(self.CoreDataUpadated),
                                      name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
                                      object: nil)
}

    func CoreDataUpadated() {
        self.coreDataUpdated = true
    }
}


class ChildViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        reloadData()
    }

    func reloadData() {
        if super.coreDataUpdated ?? false { //I always get nil for 
            super.coreDataUpdated
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Notice: I'm working on Xcode 9 beta 5 and iOS 11 with swift 4. However this code works fine on the Xcode 8 and iOS 10.3 with swift 3.

Comment: I think your `CoreDataUpadated` Method call for other `viewcontroller` and other instance while your  `ChildViewController` 's SuperClass is different instance

Comment: @MikeAlter When I use breakpoint to track app flow, it seems it is working in right flow. The `CoreDataUpadated` is getting called fine before `viewDidApear` to be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paulw11 comments, I found out with inheritance the value won't be shared. So I use `KVC` pattern as the solution. this is my code after change

```
enum coreDataState: String {
    case inserted = "inserted"
    case deleted = "deleted"
    case updated = "updated"
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .inserted: return "inserted"
        case .deleted: return "deleted"
        case .updated: return "updated"
        }
    }
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Core data update
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.CoreDataUpadated),
                                               name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    func CoreDataUpdated(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let userDictionary = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            for KV in userDictionary {
                if KV.key != "managedObjectContext" {
                    NSUserDefaultManager.SaveItem(KV.key, key: coreDataUpdateKey)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func CoreDataChanged() -> coreDataState? {
        if let currentState = NSUserDefaultManager.LoadItem(coreDataUpdateKey) as? String {
            NSUserDefaultManager.RemoveItem(coreDataUpdateKey)
            return coreDataState(rawValue: currentState)
        }
        return nil
    }
}


class ChildViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        reloadData()
    }

    func reloadData() {
        if super.CoreDataChanged() != .deleted {
            loadData()

            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Although it is possible to implement it with other patterns such as `delegate` or `override` the `CoreDataUpdated` function in child classes

Answer (score 1):

Class inheritance does not mean that subclass instances inherit the values assigned to properties in superclass instances.

You have an instance of `BaseViewController` which has a `coreDataUpdated` property and instance of `ChildViewController`, which has a `coreDataUpdated` property since it inherits from `BaseViewController`, but it's property value is unrelated to the `BaseViewController` instance property value; they are different objects.

When you say `self.coreDataUpdated = true` you are setting the property on the `BaseViewController` *instance*.

When you say `super.coreDataUpdated` you are referring to the `coreDataUpdated` property in the `ChildViewController` *instance* that is defined by it's *superclass*; since this property has never been assigned a value it is `nil`.

Since `ChildViewController` does not override `coreDataUpdated` `super.coreDataUpdated` is the same as `self.coreDataUpdated` in an instance of `ChildViewController`, so you could re-write that `if` statement as:

```
func reloadData() {
    if self.coreDataUpdated ?? false { 
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer as to why `coreDataUpdated` is `nil`

Rather than using your own `Bool`, it may be simpler to examine the `hasChanges` property of your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Comment: Actually when we define a public variable in parent view controller, it is accessible from child view controllers. So I think the problem is that my `childViewController` reload, thus `coreDataUpdated` reallocated. Is there any way to prevent this (I DON'T want to use static variables)

Comment: The property is available, but you are dealing with different object instances.  If you had two instances of `BaseViewController` you wouldn't expect them to have the same value of `coreDataUpdated`; It is the same with an instance of `ChildViewControlller`; It does have a `coreDataUpdated` property since it inherits from `BaseViewController` but instances are separate; they don't share a value.

Comment: If you want to set the value on the `ChildViewController` instance then you need to do that in `prepareForSegue` or wherever you are creating that child view controller instance; You then say `childVC.coreDataUpdated=true` or whatever, not `self.coreDataUpdated`

Comment: Thank you for your helps. Finally I find the solution. please take a look at it